# How can I speed up this Update Statement

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

Wondering if there is a way to make the SQL statement below any faster.

```
UPDATE table_one SET column_x = table_two.column_x FROM table_two
WHERE table_one.column_y = table_two.column_y;
```

Currently the above query has been running for more 3 hours. Any suggestions on how to make it faster?

**Details:**

- table_one has got 190 million records
- table_two has got 390 million records
- column_x and column_y in both tables are integers.
- The column_y in both tables is indexed

Am running on a VM with 120GB of RAM and 22 Cores with Postgresql 9.3.

Comment: A question, does the order of the `WHERE` clause matter? i.e. if we said `table_two.column_y = table_one.column_y` instead of `table_one.column_y = table_two.column_y`?

Comment: If my proposal does not help you, and you still look for solution, please add result of explain analyze of running your command.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to update all records, at least:

```
UPDATE table_one
      SET column_x = table_two.column_x
     FROM table_two
      WHERE table_one.column_y = table_two.column_y
        AND table_one.column_x != table_two.column_x;
```

Also probably might help is to create index for both field x and y for both tables.

Comment: my understanding is that a non-indexed column would handle inserts/updates faster than an indexed one hence the reason for leaving table_one.column_x Un-Indexed since its the one we are updating..

Comment: But also this construction probably can use 'index only' scan

Comment: In this case am updating all the records because I've made sure that all records in `table_one` *-the table that we are updating-* are contained in `table_two` *-the table we are updating from-*. So would your suggestion of `you do not need to update all records` still stand?

Comment: My proposal is do not update record that already have expected value.